# JSF selectOneMenu - setting value in bean

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I have selectOneMenu

```
        <h:selectOneMenu id = "current" value = "#{helloBean.currentLanguage}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{helloBean.categoryLanguages}"></f:selectItems>
        <f:ajax render = "ccData"></f:ajax>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Here is HelloBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="helloBean")
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {
    private String currentLanguage;

    public void setcurrentLanguage(String currentLanguage){
        this.currentLanguage = currentLanguage;
        }
}
```

I have a problem with setting of currentLanguage. Eclipse shows an error message that `#{helloBean.currentLanguage}` expression is not settable. And when I run my project, I get an error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /hello.xhtml @19,74 value="#{helloBean.currentLanguage}": Property 'currentLanguage' not readable on type java.lang.String
```

Comment: Java is case sensitive. Pay more attention and love to case sensitivity. Further, you forgot the getter method. Both mistakes are rather basic/trivial. Re-read that JSF book/tutorial/resource once again or look for a better one. You can get started at our JSF wiki page (hover the `[jsf]` tag below the question and then click the *info* link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BalusC pointed out, Java is case sensitive.
So when you write: `value=#{helloBean.currentLanguage}` JSF expects that you define a setter and a getter of that attribute (currentLanguage):

```
public void setCurrentLanguage(String language){
  this.currentLanguage = language;//Or whatever
}
```

(Notice the upper C in current. And add a getter)
Since you are using Eclipse, try to automatically generate access methods of your classes. (Right click -> source -> generate getter and setters)